# Need help understanding python simple linked list program

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

Below is a simple linked list program, I know how a linked list works conceptually ( adding, removing, etc) but I am finding it hard to understand how it works from an object oriented design perspective.

Code:

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self,d,n=None):
        self.data = d
        self.next_node = n   

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self,n):
        self.next_node = n

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_data(self,d):
        self.data = d

class LinkedList():

    def __init__(self,r = None):
        self.root = r
        self.size = 0 

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def add(self,d):
        new_node = Node(d,self.root)
        self.root = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def get_list(self):
        new_pointer = self.root
        while new_pointer:
            print new_pointer.get_data()
            new_pointer = new_pointer.get_next()

    def remove(self,d):
        this_node = self.root
        prev_node = None
        while this_node:
            if this_node.get_data() == d:
                if prev_node:
                    prev_node.set_next(this_node.get_next())
                else:
                    self.root = this_node
                self.size -= 1
                return True
            else:
                prev_node = this_node
                this_node = this_node.get_next()
        return False

    def find(self,d):
        this_node = self.root
        while this_node:
            if this_node.get_data() == d:
                return d
            else:
                this_node = this_node.get_next()
        return None

myList = LinkedList()
myList.add(5)
myList.add(8)
myList.add(12)
myList.get_list()
```

I have couple questions here..

1. How is it storing the values. As far as I understand each variable can hold one value. So how does data / next_node hold multiple values. And does next_node hold the memory location of the next node?
2. `new_pointer.get_data()` How is new_pointer able to access get_data()? Don't we need to have an instance to access methods of Node?

This question may be silly, but I am quiet new to object oriented programming. If someone can answer these questions or post an external link addressing these questions it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot to be said. Study Python, there are many good resources available.

Answer (score 1):

1. `next_node` is an instance of `Node` and so it has its own `data` field.  `next_node` is a reference to the node object, which is some memory address (however it is not a C-like pointer, as you don't need to dereference it or anything).
2. I'm assuming you are talking about `get_list()`.  new_pointer *is* an instance of `Node`.  (unless it is `None`, in which case you would never get into the `get_data()` call).  When you do an `add`, you create this instance of `Node` and set `root` to it.  Then in `get_list` you set `new_pointer` to `root`.

Comment: How is `next_node` an instance of class `Node`? Is'nt it a variable in class `Node`, I know that new_node is instance of `Node` because of `new_node = Node(d,self.root)`.

Comment: When you have a LinkedList with at least one node, and you `add()` a new node, you construct this new node with a reference to the root.  Notice in `Node`'s `__init__()`, the old root (which points to some node) becomes the next of a new node, and the new root then is set to this new node.

Answer (score 0):

`myList.root` is storing one value only that is the root of the list. See initially when you do:

```
myList = LinkedList()
```

in memory `myList.root = None` (according to `__init__` of `LinkedList`). Now:

```
myList.add(1)
```

Then this statement is called:

```
new_node = Node(d,self.root)        #Note here self.root = None
```

and then:
    def **init**(self,d,n=None):
            self.data = d
            self.next_node = n
So our list is  :  `1--> None`.Now:

```
myList.add(2)
```

then again this statement is called:

```
new_node = Node(d,self.root)        #Note here self.root has some value
```

now a new node object is created and its next is assigned to `myList.root`.
So our list becomes : `2-->1--> None`
Going in similar fashion whole list is assigned.
Key thing to note here is that myList.root is always storing the top most node which in turn holds the next node and so on.

For your second question, it is quite clear from above explaination that always the object of class `node` is available to `myList.root` which in turn has `next_node` which is again an object of 'node'. So they all have access to 'get_data()' method.